# Determination of Invertibility

Tags: inverse, nonlinear-system

If  for example $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)= x_1- \sin(x_3)$ is a nonlinear function of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, how can be understood that for example $\frac{df(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}{dx_3}$ is invertible or not ?

Comment: Sorry for its unwanted deletion.

Comment: The derivative $\partial_{x_3}f$ would also be a function $\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^1$. It cannot be invertible, it must have been $\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ for the chance of it being invertible (and to have a Jacobian non-zero at the point).

Comment: @mobiuseng, thanks for your help, but the question is about functions and necessarily it's not  related to a matrix.

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment. Any smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m<n$ cannot be invertible. If I'm wrong, I would like a counter example. Linear functions (represented by matrices) are just simplest examples of such non-invertable functions.

Comment: @mobiuseng, could you explain more about "Linear functions (represented by matrices) are just simplest examples of such non-invertable functions."?

Comment: Linear function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, that is $f(ax)=af(x)$ for a number $a$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, can be represented by a matrix $A$. If $n=m$ and matrix $A$ invertible, $f$ is also invertible.

Comment: I started doubting my statement. If we allow $f$ to be any kind of function, $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ can be invertible even when $m<n$ since both $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ have the same cardinality, and thus we can have one-to-one correspondence. So, now I wonder what restriction I need to impose on $f$ for it to be invertible only for $n=m$. Infinitely differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward, always-working, follow-these-steps-to-get-what-you-need answer to your question. In general, proving that a function is invertible can be a very hard thing to do.

---

However, in your case, it's simple. Since $f$ is independent of $x_2$, it is not invertible (for example, $f(0,0,0,0) = f(0,1,0,0)$). The same is true for all its derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for your effective help. what about if there are all variables in the $f$ ?

Comment: @Rwy5 Like I said, there is no general method. You take it one problem at a time. For example, you can tell if there is a squared variable, the function is not likely to be bijective everywhere, since $(-x)^2=x^2$. But that's just one of the hundreds of things you can use.

Comment: thanks, could you introduce me some of the topics that when I face these cases that there are all variables, can obtain and analysis its answer.

Comment: @Rwy5 No, I cannot. I mean, I can, but (1) this is not what this site is for and (2) the only way you can effectively learn these things is through one of three options: *practice*, **practice** or ***practice***.